# Quantum rigid rotator Schrodinger equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, rigid-body-dynamics

I am studying the quantum rigid rotator from  [Introduction to modern physics](https://menglim498.files.wordpress.com/2013/04/introduction_to_modern_physics.pdf) and I don't understand why they make the substition r ->1. Dimensionally, it makes sense to me, but I am not able to explain why it is correct or if it's not wrong to just drop the term with a derivative with respect to r in the Schrodinger equation. Can someone help me visualize why this substition is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The explanation is quite simple.

The textbook just decided to consider a *rigid* rotator,
meaning the two masses are separated by a *fixed* distance $r$.
If the distance $r$ between the two masses would be variable,
then we would not call it a *rigid* rotator, but a
*flexible* or *elastic* rotator.

Treating a diatomic molecule as a rigid rotator
is just an approximation to simplify the mathematics.
Physically it means you neglect the vibrations of the molecule
due an oscillating distance $r$.
This approximation is valid because in the real molecule
the distance $r$ varies only by relatively small amounts $\Delta r$.